# WCF The contract name 'IMetadataExchange' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, endpoint

i have been working with a web service and it was working just fine then i added     
 attribute in the behaviors section in both App.config & Web.config and it crashed 
the error is ***

> WCF The contract name 'IMetadataExchange' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service

---

, below you find the xml code for my App.config for my service library .. under it you find the xml code for my web.config file for my website thanks in advance for your help :)
my App.config for my library

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="FluoraPinServiceLibrary.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="FluoraPinServiceLibrary.IFluoraPinServices">
          <identity>
            <dns value="192.168.1.3" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.3:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->

          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="Throttled">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->

          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceThrottling
        maxConcurrentCalls="4"
        maxConcurrentSessions="4"
        maxConcurrentInstances="4"
          />
          <serviceMetadata
            httpGetEnabled="true"
            httpGetUrl=""
          />


        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

and that's the code for my Web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" executionTimeout="72000" maxRequestLength="4096" minFreeThreads="72" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="88" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->

          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      <behavior  name="Throttled">
          <serviceThrottling 
            maxConcurrentCalls="4" 
            maxConcurrentSessions="4" 
            maxConcurrentInstances="4"
          />
          <serviceMetadata 
            httpGetEnabled="true" 
            httpGetUrl=""
          />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That's a whole load of totally useless information. "then i added attribute and it crashed". What attribute, where, what did the crash message say?

Answer (score 12):

Your default behavior has only **serviceDebug** tag.  You need to add **serviceMetadata**  tag.

```
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->

      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceMetadata/>
    </behavior>
```

You can find details [here](http://kirandhappuri.wordpress.com/2014/05/14/wcf-the-contract-name-imetadataexchange-could-not-be-found-in-the-list-of-contracts/)

Answer (score 6):

To `IMetadataExchange` be findable, declare `serviceMetadata`:

```
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
            <serviceMetadata />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: Perfect! This is the only answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove this line and it will works like a charm

```
 <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your default (unnamed) behaviour does not include a `serviceMetadata` tag. You should include it (copy it from the "Throttled" behaviour) or use your new behaviour for your service endpoints.